# Is this sentence considered rude in English

Tags: politeness

I am writing to a client, and I finished my email by:

> Please let me know at your earliest convenience.

Do you consider this rude in English culture? I wrote it as an exact translate from my language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that wouldn't be considered rude. Just to elaborate:

The "please" and "your convenience" make it quite polite.

If you said, "I must have an answer now", that would be demanding, if not rude.

Answer (score 3):

That phrasing would be considered polite and professional. It's interesting that it was a direct translation because that's actually a fairly standard way to end a request over email in English business culture.